# Проблема с кнопкой в верстке

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mulish:wght@300;400;700&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Mulish", sans-serif;
  padding: 56px 1em 0 1em;
}

h1 {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 56px;
}

p {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 32px;
}

.h-link {
  font-family: "Mulish", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.h-link.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header-consult__btn {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #458FF6;
  border-radius: 55px;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.header {
  max-width: 1250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header-nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 86px;
}

.logo {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.header-list {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.headerNav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.h-item {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 40px;
}

.headerMain {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 109px 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 109px;
}

.h-burger {
  display: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.h-burger:active {
  background-color: black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .headerMain {
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .illustration {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    order: 1;
  }
  .header-text {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    order: 2;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .header-list {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    right: -120%;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .h-burger {
    display: block;
  }
  .header-list._active {
    right: 0;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

.header-text {
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
  -ms-grid-row-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.header-text h1 {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.header-text p {
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

.our-services {
  max-width: 1169px;
  margin: 192px auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.our-services h2 {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 56px;
  margin-bottom: 26px;
}

.our-services hr {
  width: 56px;
  border: #000 solid 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto 33px;
}

.our-services p {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.our-services button {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #458FF6;
  border: 1.4px solid #458FF6;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 55px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0 51px;
}

.list-item__our-services {
  list-style: none;
  min-width: 350px;
  max-width: 350px;
  text-align: left !important;
  padding-top: 52px;
  padding-left: 36px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 40px 50px rgba(229, 233, 246, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 10px 40px 50px rgba(229, 233, 246, 0.4);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.list-item__our-services h3 {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 56px;
}

.list-item__our-services p {
  text-align: left !important;
}

.grid-list__our-services {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 36px;
  margin: 0 auto 69px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/import.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="header-nav">
      <nav class="headerNav" role="navigation">
        <div class="logo">
          <svg width="160" height="41" viewBox="0 0 160 41" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M58.856 15.456H53.288V12.912H67.568V15.456H61.976V30H58.856V15.456ZM74.1209 17.592C74.5849 17.592 74.9849 17.656 75.3209 17.784L75.2969 20.52C74.7849 20.312 74.2569 20.208 73.7129 20.208C72.6889 20.208 71.9049 20.504 71.3609 21.096C70.8329 21.688 70.5689 22.472 70.5689 23.448V30H67.5929V21.312C67.5929 20.032 67.5289 18.888 67.4009 17.88H70.2089L70.4489 20.016C70.7529 19.232 71.2329 18.632 71.8889 18.216C72.5449 17.8 73.2889 17.592 74.1209 17.592ZM88.349 17.88V30H85.397V28.056C85.029 28.728 84.501 29.256 83.813 29.64C83.125 30.008 82.341 30.192 81.461 30.192C80.405 30.192 79.469 29.936 78.653 29.424C77.837 28.912 77.205 28.184 76.757 27.24C76.309 26.296 76.085 25.2 76.085 23.952C76.085 22.704 76.309 21.6 76.757 20.64C77.221 19.664 77.861 18.912 78.677 18.384C79.493 17.84 80.421 17.568 81.461 17.568C82.341 17.568 83.125 17.76 83.813 18.144C84.501 18.512 85.029 19.032 85.397 19.704V17.88H88.349ZM82.277 27.84C83.269 27.84 84.037 27.496 84.581 26.808C85.125 26.12 85.397 25.152 85.397 23.904C85.397 22.624 85.125 21.64 84.581 20.952C84.037 20.264 83.261 19.92 82.253 19.92C81.261 19.92 80.485 20.28 79.925 21C79.381 21.704 79.109 22.688 79.109 23.952C79.109 25.2 79.381 26.16 79.925 26.832C80.485 27.504 81.269 27.84 82.277 27.84ZM97.3524 14.712C96.0564 14.712 95.4084 15.424 95.4084 16.848V17.88H98.1204V20.136H95.4084V30H92.4084V20.136H90.1044V17.88H92.4084V16.704C92.4084 15.264 92.7684 14.16 93.4884 13.392C94.2244 12.608 95.2724 12.216 96.6324 12.216C97.3844 12.216 98.0164 12.312 98.5284 12.504V14.88C98.0804 14.768 97.6884 14.712 97.3524 14.712ZM111.904 17.88V30H108.952V28.056C108.584 28.728 108.056 29.256 107.368 29.64C106.68 30.008 105.896 30.192 105.016 30.192C103.96 30.192 103.024 29.936 102.208 29.424C101.392 28.912 100.76 28.184 100.312 27.24C99.8637 26.296 99.6397 25.2 99.6397 23.952C99.6397 22.704 99.8637 21.6 100.312 20.64C100.776 19.664 101.416 18.912 102.232 18.384C103.048 17.84 103.976 17.568 105.016 17.568C105.896 17.568 106.68 17.76 107.368 18.144C108.056 18.512 108.584 19.032 108.952 19.704V17.88H111.904ZM105.832 27.84C106.824 27.84 107.592 27.496 108.136 26.808C108.68 26.12 108.952 25.152 108.952 23.904C108.952 22.624 108.68 21.64 108.136 20.952C107.592 20.264 106.816 19.92 105.808 19.92C104.816 19.92 104.04 20.28 103.48 21C102.936 21.704 102.664 22.688 102.664 23.952C102.664 25.2 102.936 26.16 103.48 26.832C104.04 27.504 104.824 27.84 105.832 27.84ZM115.171 12.336H118.147V30H115.171V12.336ZM133.141 17.88V29.616C133.141 31.504 132.621 32.936 131.581 33.912C130.541 34.888 129.013 35.376 126.997 35.376C125.125 35.376 123.477 34.984 122.053 34.2L122.533 31.92C124.005 32.688 125.469 33.072 126.925 33.072C129.085 33.072 130.165 32 130.165 29.856V27.456C129.797 28.112 129.261 28.648 128.557 29.064C127.853 29.464 127.061 29.664 126.181 29.664C125.125 29.664 124.181 29.416 123.349 28.92C122.533 28.408 121.893 27.696 121.429 26.784C120.981 25.856 120.757 24.8 120.757 23.616C120.757 22.432 120.981 21.384 121.429 20.472C121.893 19.544 122.533 18.832 123.349 18.336C124.181 17.824 125.125 17.568 126.181 17.568C127.077 17.568 127.869 17.76 128.557 18.144C129.261 18.512 129.797 19.032 130.165 19.704V17.88H133.141ZM126.973 27.312C127.965 27.312 128.741 26.984 129.301 26.328C129.877 25.672 130.165 24.768 130.165 23.616C130.165 22.464 129.885 21.56 129.325 20.904C128.765 20.248 127.981 19.92 126.973 19.92C125.981 19.92 125.197 20.248 124.621 20.904C124.061 21.56 123.781 22.464 123.781 23.616C123.781 24.768 124.061 25.672 124.621 26.328C125.197 26.984 125.981 27.312 126.973 27.312ZM147.974 17.88V30H145.022V28.056C144.654 28.728 144.126 29.256 143.438 29.64C142.75 30.008 141.966 30.192 141.086 30.192C140.03 30.192 139.094 29.936 138.278 29.424C137.462 28.912 136.83 28.184 136.382 27.24C135.934 26.296 135.71 25.2 135.71 23.952C135.71 22.704 135.934 21.6 136.382 20.64C136.846 19.664 137.486 18.912 138.302 18.384C139.118 17.84 140.046 17.568 141.086 17.568C141.966 17.568 142.75 17.76 143.438 18.144C144.126 18.512 144.654 19.032 145.022 19.704V17.88H147.974ZM141.902 27.84C142.894 27.84 143.662 27.496 144.206 26.808C144.75 26.12 145.022 25.152 145.022 23.904C145.022 22.624 144.75 21.64 144.206 20.952C143.662 20.264 142.886 19.92 141.878 19.92C140.886 19.92 140.11 20.28 139.55 21C139.006 21.704 138.734 22.688 138.734 23.952C138.734 25.2 139.006 26.16 139.55 26.832C140.11 27.504 140.894 27.84 141.902 27.84ZM157.769 17.592C158.233 17.592 158.633 17.656 158.969 17.784L158.945 20.52C158.433 20.312 157.905 20.208 157.361 20.208C156.337 20.208 155.553 20.504 155.009 21.096C154.481 21.688 154.217 22.472 154.217 23.448V30H151.241V21.312C151.241 20.032 151.177 18.888 151.049 17.88H153.857L154.097 20.016C154.401 19.232 154.881 18.632 155.537 18.216C156.193 17.8 156.937 17.592 157.769 17.592Z"
                          fill="#233348"/>
                    <circle cx="20.5" cy="20.5" r="20.5" fill="#458FF6"/>
                    <path d="M19.344 15.244H13.312V12.488H28.782V15.244H22.724V31H19.344V15.244Z" fill="white"/>
                </svg>
        </div>
        <button onclick="$('.header-list').toggleClass('_active')" class="h-burger"><svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M3 5C3 4.44772 3.44772 4 4 4H16C16.5523 4 17 4.44772 17 5C17 5.55228 16.5523 6 16 6H4C3.44772 6 3 5.55228 3 5Z" fill="#000"/>
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M3 10C3 9.44772 3.44772 9 4 9H16C16.5523 9 17 9.44772 17 10C17 10.5523 16.5523 11 16 11H4C3.44772 11 3 10.5523 3 10Z" fill="#000"/>
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M3 15C3 14.4477 3.44772 14 4 14H16C16.5523 14 17 14.4477 17 15C17 15.5523 16.5523 16 16 16H4C3.44772 16 3 15.5523 3 15Z" fill="#000"/>
            </svg>
            </button>
        <ul class="header-list">
          <li class="h-item"><a href="#" class="h-link active">Home</a></li>
          <li class="h-item"><a href="#" class="h-link">Find a doctor</a></li>
          <li class="h-item"><a href="#" class="h-link">Apps</a></li>
          <li class="h-item"><a href="#" class="h-link">Testimonials</a></li>
          <li class="h-item"><a href="#" class="h-link">About us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="header-main">
      <main class="headerMain">
        <div class="header-text">
          <h1>Virtual healthcare for you</h1>
          <p>Trafalgar provides progressive, and affordable healthcare, accessible on mobile and online for everyone</p>
          <button class="header-consult__btn">Consult today</button>
        </div>
        <div class="illustration">
          <img src="img/illustration.png" alt="main header illustration" class="h-illustration" />
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="our-services">
    <h2>Our services</h2>
    <hr>
    <p>We provide to you the best choiches for you. Adjust it to your health needs and make sure your undergo treatment with our highly qualified doctors you can consult with us which type of service is suitable for your health</p>
    <ul class="grid-list__our-services">
      <li class="list-item__our-services">
        <img src="img/our-services/search.png" alt="Search doctor">
        <h3>Search doctor</h3>
        <p>Choose your doctor from thousands of specialist, general, and trusted hospitals</p>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item__our-services">
        <img src="img/our-services/pharmacy.png" alt="Online pharmacy">
        <h3>Online pharmacy</h3>
        <p>Buy your medicines with our mobile application with a simple delivery system</p>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item__our-services">
        <img src="img/our-services/consultation.png" alt="Consultation">
        <h3>Consultation</h3>
        <p>Free consultation with our trusted doctors and get the best recomendations</p>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item__our-services">
        <img src="img/our-services/details.png" alt="Details info">
        <h3>Details info</h3>
        <p>Free consultation with our trusted doctors and get the best recomendations</p>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item__our-services">
        <img src="img/our-services/emergency.png" alt="Emergency care">
        <h3>Emergency care</h3>
        <p>You can get 24/7 urgent care for yourself or your children and your lovely family</p>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item__our-services">
        <img src="img/our-services/tracking.png" alt="Tracking">
        <h3>Tracking</h3>
        <p>Track and save your medical history and health data </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button>Learn more</button>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Если вы нажмете на "Выполнить код" вы увидите страницу
нажмите на бургер меню - нажалась 1 раз
нажмите еще раз - не нажалась?
Почему? обьясните как эту чертову кнопку нажать еще раз
пожалуйста) это не сильно срочно.
Помогите...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь происходит наложение элементов, т.е после нажатия на "бургер" открывается меню, которое имеет свойство `position: absolute;` и оно перекрывает остальные элементы.

Решить это можно задав для кнопки следующие свойства:

```
.h-burger {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```